# How can I add a "sender name" in a PHP contact form?

Tags: php

Considering that my experience with PHP is very limited, I customised a contact form that I found and it works as I want. The only thing that's bothering me is that I can't find a way to include a "sender name" in it, which means that when I recieve the e-mail, the sender field is empty as seen below.

[image]

I would like to set "Contato" as the sender name. Is it possible?

Any tips on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    } 

    $to_Email       = "giovanna.coppola@yahoo.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Formul&#225;rio de Contato (Site)'; //Subject line for emails

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        die();
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone       = filter_var($_POST["userPhone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<6) // If length is less than 6 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Nome muito curto ou campo vazio.');
        exit();
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Insira um e-mail va&#769;lido.');
        exit();
    }
    if(!is_numeric($user_Phone)) //check entered data is numbers
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Esse campo so&#769; aceita n&#250;meros.');
        exit();
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<10) //check emtpy message
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Mensagem curta demais.');
        exit();
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "rn" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "rn" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $message = 'Nome: '.$user_Name."\r\n".
           'E-mail: '.$user_Email."\r\n".
           'Telefone: '.$user_Phone."\r\n".
           'Mensagem: '.$user_Message;

$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 N&#227;o foi poss&#237;vel enviar. Tente novamente.');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo 'Ol&#225;, '.$user_Name.'. Agradecemos o contato! ';
        echo 'Retornaremos o mais breve poss&#237;vel.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Missing \ for r and n in headers, fix it. And use From: line to be 'From: SenderName <' . $user_Email . '>' . "\r\n" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "rn" .
```

to

```
$headers = 'From: '.$user_Name.' <'.$user_Email. '>'. "\r\n" .
```

see example #4 in the manual for `mail()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3416

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPmailer?

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail

```
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'Sender name here');
```